# angularjs - Unable to properly display array values from ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to display values from an array using ng-repeat, but i'm clearly missing something here and I cannot figure out what it is exactly.

Here's an example: http://codepen.io/nickimola/pen/dMNawj?editors=1010

json object:

```
  $scope.data = [
    {"id": 0, "settings": {"SP": 21,"Active": false,"Output": true,"Link": [2,3,4]}},
    {"id": 1, "settings": {"SP": 1,"Active": true,"Output": true,"Link": [5]}},
    {"id": 2, "settings": {"SP": 30,"Active": false,"Output": true,"Link": []}},
  ];
```

html:

```
<ion-content>
         <ion-list class="list">
        <div ng-repeat="b in data">
            <ion-item class="item item-stable"
                      ng-click="toggleGroup(b)"
                      ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(b)}">
                {{b.id}}
            </ion-item>
            <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in b.settings" ng-show="isGroupShown(b)">
              <div ng-repeat="links in key" ng-if="key == 'Link'">
              <ion-item class="item-accordion">
                  {{links}}
                 </ion-item>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

I would like to display only the numbers inside `Link` array, but at the moment all I can see is all the letters in the word "LINK", one for each accordion element.
Any help?

Thanks a lot

Comment: try with "links in value" not "links in key"

Comment: it was so simple. Thanks a lot, it worked.
If you want to explain and had this as an answer i can select it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is:

```
<div ng-repeat="links in value" ng-if="key == 'Link'">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in b.settings" ng-show="isGroupShown(b)">
>               <div ng-repeat="links in **value**" ng-if="key == 'Link'">
>               <ion-item class="item-accordion">
>                   {{links}}
>                  </ion-item> </div>
```

Please replace "key" with "value" in your inner "ng-repeat". Thanks.